# Implied Indirect Discourse in Opening of Francis Bacon's Novum Organon?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, oratio-obliqua

Here is part of the beginning of Bacon's Novum Organon:
...rationem instituit, quam viventibus et posteris notam fieri, ipsorum interesse putavit.

I don't understand NOTAM FIERI. Perhaps it is implied indirect discourse? As I read the sentence, it goes like this: "He established a method (RATIONEM), which (QUAM)..., he thought would benefit them (IPSORUM -- i.e. the present and future generations)."

But, again, I just don't see how to render NOTAM FIERI. The translators of the recent-ish Cambridge edition have something like this: "He established a method, which he thought would benefit them, were it to be known." They make NOTAM FIERI a kind of conditional-thought ("were it to be known"), which seems right to me, but I can't give a good explanation of the grammar that licenses such a translation.

Comment: *interesse putavit* "he thought it important", *rationem notam fieri* "that the reason become known". I think that *fieri* and its accusatives are the predicate (or are they the subject?) of *interesse*.

Comment: Thanks, @Figulus. I share your puzzlement about the subject of interesse. To put the matter semantically, I might ask what Bacon thinks is "of great importance"? (1) The method or (2) That the method be known. I recognize that these two thoughts are hard to distinguish, but, again, my question is pretty strictly grammatical.

Comment: It worth adding the full sentence: *FRANCISCUS de Verulamio sic cogitavit: talemque apud se rationem instituit, quam Viventibus et Posteris notam fieri ipsorum interesse putavit.* . I don't see it, but In theory *quam* could be a correlative of *talem* or even something like a correlative to oppose "apud se":  *[tam] apud se quam viventibus*.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and for including the full sentence. I am pretty certain quam is correlative with talem, but I still don't see how that helps account for fieri (unless, as @Figulus suggested in the first comment, it -- fieri, I mean -- is governed by interesse).

Comment: @BrendanBoyle This usage of *interesse* is impersonal, so *quam* alone cannot be the subject, because it has none. But it can stand, among other things, with an AcI, which grammars irritatingly call a "subject clause." So – semantically speaking – he must have thought it of importance that the method become known. I wouldn't know what *notam fieri* would be doing in the sentence otherwise.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel I agree with you that it is strange to classify a verb as impersonal and then speak of its subject clauses, but I don’t have a better terminology everybody can understand. How do you call those AcI’s with which _interesse_ can stand, if not _subject clauses?_

Comment: @Dario I have no better terminology either; plus, *interest* can also stand with neutr. pron. like *hoc* (and also with *nihil*), so its impersonality is somewhat iffy anyway.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Many thanks for (1) the reminder that this usage of interesse is impersonal and (2) that quam...fieri can (must!) stand as its subject. I appreciate all the help. (First time user of LSE -- forgive any errors I made in formatting or the like! I'll be back!)

Comment: @dario Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Not the most straightforward English, but...

*... such that he thought that it becoming known to the living and to posterity would benefit them.*

*Putavit* governs the infinitive *interesse,* which is constructed with the genitive of the interested party, *ipsorum;* *(quam = rationem) notam fieri* acts as the **subject** of *interesse.*

Bacon thought that the fact that the method be known was of great importance for the present and future human kind.

Note that *interesse* requires strange forms for first and second person pronouns (*meā, tuā,* etc...) but with *ipsi* a regular genitive plural is OK. I am sure this has been discussed before in LSE...